# Can <header> and <footer> place outside of <article> and still describe about it?

Tags: html

I have a `single.html` page. It is a page to display only one post. So I wonder if machine like bots and browsers would understand the metadata for the post if I place `<header>/<footer>` out of `<article>` (not nested)?
Here is my sample code:

```
<header><!-- document header --></header>
<main id='post'>
    <header><!-- time & title of post stay here --></header>
    <article class='content'><!-- content of post stay here --></article>
    <footer><!-- other data of post stay here --></footer>
</main>
<footer><!-- document footer --></footer>
```

I want to know if this structure can make Firefox can recognize correctly the content for Firefox's Reader Mode(*) and search engine bots can crawl exactly the data its looking for.

(*): I mean FF Reader Mode can get the title from `#post > header`, get the whole content from `#post > .content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing researching for a while, I decided to combine schema.org with HTML semantic tags.

```
<!-- itemtype='https://schema.org/Blog' in <body> -->
<header><!-- document header --></header>
<main>
    <article id='post' itemprop='blogPost' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
        <header><!-- time & title of post stay here --></header>
        <div class='content' itemprop='articleBody'><!-- content of post stay here --></div>
        <footer><!-- other data of post stay here --></footer>
    </article>
</main>
<footer><!-- document footer --></footer>
```

With this, the machine will be able to read and understand the connection between elements. In Firefox Reader Mode, it seems the reader still miss post title and author. But the main content is still good to go.